# Django module Issue/running django

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, pycharm

Started having issues running Django.  Install runs without error, however when I check the version packages that show "already satisified" are not found.

I've removed my .local and re-installed files, no change.

```
% pip3 install /path/.../Django-3.0b1/ --user
Processing /path/.../Django-3.0b1
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in /usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Django==3.0b1) (2018.5)
Requirement already satisfied: sqlparse in /path/.../.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Django==3.0b1) (0.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: asgiref in path/.../.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (from Django==3.0b1) (3.2.3)

Installing collected packages: Django
  Running setup.py install for Django ... done
Successfully installed Django-3.0b1
```

```
% python3 -m django --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/.../python/3.7.3b/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in
_run_module_as_main   "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/path/.../python/3.7.3b/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code  exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/path/.../Django-3.0b1/django/__main__.py", line 6, in <module>  from django.core import management
  File "/path/.../Django-3.0b1/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 14, in <module> from django.core.management.base import (
  File "/path/.../Django-3.0b1/django/core/management/base.py", line 11, in <module> from django.core import checks
  File "/path/.../Django-3.0b1/django/core/checks/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>  import django.core.checks.database  # NOQA isort:skip
  File "/path/.../Django-3.0b1/django/core/checks/database.py", line 1, in <module> from django.db import connections
  File "/path/.../Django-3.0b1/django/db/__init__.py", line 2, in <module> from django.db.utils import (
  File "/path/.../Django-3.0b1/django/db/utils.py", line 5, in <module>  from asgiref.local import Local
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'asgiref'
```

Comment: Tried upgrading to asgiref-3.2.7 and no help.  Also,same issue on command line and running in pycharm.

Comment: You have a system python version 3.6 and I assume a user version 3.7. The pip3 is from system, but missing deps are installed in user install. Quite messy. This is why virtualenvs exist. If you're deadset on using a user install, you need to know how to massage PATH.